# Codeigniter insert and select a field in one query

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I am inserting a record successfully in the database table. The primary key (member_id) is set to auto_increment. I want when I insert a member record and a new member_id is created, to retrieve that same record id immediately from the same query. Is that possible?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db->insert_id()`  will get the latest id from the database.

See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->insert('...');
$member_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

This would work also, its the standart PHP function.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_insert_id.asp